# Any example of pausing and resuming JMS messages using JMSQueueControl

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I read in [the ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.1.0/management.html) that we can pause and resume JMS message using `JMSQueueControl`, but I'm not able to find the interface in the latest jars.

Any code example would be appreciated.

Comment: You're referencing _really_ old documentation from version 1.1.0 (notice the "1.1.0" in the URL). The latest documentation is [here](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html). The `JMSQueueControl` was removed a few years back. You should use `QueueControl` instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the latest documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#queue-management), you can use `QueueControl` and there is such a class in the API.

> Pausing and resuming Queues
>
> The QueueControl can pause and resume the underlying queue. When a
> queue is paused, it will receive messages but will not deliver them.
> When it's resumed, it'll begin delivering the queued messages, if any.

Example of Usage:

```java
String eapObjectName = "org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"default\",component=addresses,address=\"jms.queue.exampleQueue\",subcomponent=queues,routing-type=\"anycast\",queue=\"jms.queue.exampleQueue\"";
MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName objectName = ObjectName.getInstance(eapObjectName);
QueueControl queueControl = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(mBeanServer,objectName,QueueControl.class,false)

queueControl.pause();
```

References:

- [JavaDoc](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/QueueControl.html)
- [Github](https://github.com/bershath/eap-clients/blob/aee5f911491d3a57270ef448793fd1178eed8f7c/eap-timers-jmx/src/main/java/org/jboss/labs/eap/timers/jmx/TimedNotifierTMR.java)

Comment: may I get QueueControl object from an existing queue instead of registering a new queue?

Comment: Yes. In fact, the example *is* getting a `QueueControl` for an existing queue named `jms.queue.exampleQueue`.